# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input in the code below

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to recreate and fix a bug in a mobile game made with html css js and built using Cordova. Im having the error in the screenshots below that says: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input and somewhere it points to html line one and other one points to this try and catch code below. in my search for the root of this error i encountered that all questions asked about this error is asked and answered about individual problems from users so i had to ask about my individual problem with this error as well. how can i find out the reason this error happens? how can i try to fix it? how can i maybe recreate it again?

note: line 8804 in the error is line 7 here the content-type line.

```js
try {
  fetch("https://mmapi.cloudtree.cloud/AddUpdateRecords_v4.php", {
    "headers": {
      "accept": "*/*",
      "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
      "pragma": "no-cache",
      "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
      "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
      "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site"
    },
    "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
    "method": "POST",
    "mode": "cors",
    "credentials": "omit",
    "body": (new URLSearchParams({
      'login': "iu8tjhfgs63",
      'player_id': profile_id_var,
      'play_lang': build_lang_abbr,
      'play_mode': play_mode_var,
      'letters': max_guess_length_var,
      'level': level_var,
      'time_spent': time_spent_var,
      'num_guess': num_guess_var,
      'xp': xp,
      'hint': hints_used,
      'ghint': g_hints_used,
      'winorloss': WinOrLose,
      'add_xp_flag': add_xp_flag,
      'coins': valueListener.coins,
      'map_lvl': last_unlocked_map_lvl
    })).toString()
  }).then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
  }).then(function(rank_remote) {
    show_VicGo_coin(rank_remote.coins_to_add);
    if (check_is_marathon_robothon()) {
      Marathon_Medal.push(rank_remote);
      if (marathon_game_counter == marathon_game_total) Marathon_Init_Medals();
      return;
    }

    document.getElementById("Victory_award_rank").innerHTML = rank_remote.rank;
    var Vic_medal = rank_remote.medals;
    var medal_html = "";
    var medals;
    for (medals in Vic_medal) {
      var newTag = "";
      var modalText = Vic_medal[medals];
      if (multipleAWARDSID.includes(medals)) {
        newTag = returnMultiple(medals);
      } else {
        newTag = returnSolo(medals);
      }
      medal_html += "<div class='VG_medal_items' data-text='" + modalText + "'>" + newTag + "</div>";
    }
    Show_Medal(medal_html);
    rate_us_trigger = (rank_remote.rateus_flag == 1);
  });
} catch (err) {
  hide_object(document.getElementsByClassName("VG_medal"));
  ClassAdd(document.getElementsByClassName("VG_info"), "Single_info");
  ClassAdd_ByID(Victory_award_Text, "Single_award_Text");
  show_VicGo_coin(0);
}
} else {
  hide_object(document.getElementsByClassName("VG_medal"));
  ClassAdd(document.getElementsByClassName("VG_info"), "Single_info");
  ClassAdd_ByID(Victory_award_Text, "Single_award_Text");
  show_VicGo_coin(0);
}
```

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` the response from the server is not valid JSON - so the cause of the error is server code, which you haven't shown. The solution is to fix the server code

Comment: i have only access to html css js.  is there any problem that could happen here in the js in any way? @Bravo and by server code what do you mean?

Comment: the issue is with the data that is being returned ... you could use `return res.text();` and process the text rather than expect it to be JSON ... what does the response actually look like (in browser developer tools) - server code is the code that sends the response to your request - the PHP on `https://mmapi.cloudtree.cloud/AddUpdateRecords_v4.php`